# php implode function not working on concatenated variables

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have multiple arrays which I am passing to a file sales_process.php on the form submit action. The arrays are named like this :  boards1 = {a , b , c}, boards2 = {b , c , d}, boards3 = {a , c , d} . . and so on (The values are not a,b,c,d). I am passing them through multiple 'multiple select boxes' in my form like this where a,b,c,d are my multiple select options :

```
for ($count=1;$count<10;$count++)
echo "<td>"."<select name='boards".$count."[]' multiple='multiple'>".showOptionsDrop($boards,$arr)."</select></td>";
```

Now when i pass them to the file sales_process.php, i want to convert these arrays into strings using implode function so that i can store them into my 'schools' table. In sales_process.php file, I am doing this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
$board = implode(',',${'boards'.$i});
$query = "UPDATE schools SET board = '$board' where schoolcode = (some_no)";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error in updating table :".mysql_error());
}
```

So in this way, every time my loop runs, the values of boardsX gets converted into string and gets stored in the table, where X is 1,2,3.... and so on.
The problem is the implode function is not working and giving error :
`Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\relationshipReport\sales_process.php on line 18`

Now if you say that the variable `${'boards'.$i}` is not an array, i did this and found out that its giving me an array only :

```
$i=1;
var_dump(${'boards'.$i});
print_r(${'boards'.$i});
```

which gives the output as :

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "CBSE" [1]=> string(4) "ICSE" [2]=> string(5) "IGCSE" }
Array ( [0] => CBSE [1] => ICSE [2] => IGCSE )
```

I hope my question is clear. Please help me in finding out whats going wrong in the implode function. If you don't understand the question, please mention it.

Comment: When working with arrays in PHP, wrap with square braces, `[` and `]`, rather than their curly counterparts. Try fixing this and reporting back. :)

Comment: Well, it's an array when $i is 1, but is it always an array?

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli : yes the variable which i am passing is in the format of 'boardsX' where X is an integer value, so its always an array when concatenated.

Comment: @Spiritfyre : i did $['boards'.$i] only to find out that its giving me an expression error :(

Comment: @Spiritfyre : to be precise, the error is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\relationshipReport\sales_process.php on line 18`

Comment: You need to access it as `$_POST['boards'.$i]` or `$_GET['boards'.$i]`, depending how you sent the content from the form.

Comment: But if the user is not selecting anything in one of the arrays (say, boards5 is empty), it will not be an array.

Comment: @Spiritfyre : Im so sorry, I forgot to mention that i have already done that and my variables are being passed by $_POST method as $boards1[] , $boards2[] and so on ... Does that helps in solving this problem ?

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli : I assure you that all the arrays have atleast one value. None of them is empty.

Comment: Yes, it should. I'll reply as an answer, with some code that should help solve your hassle.

Comment: Why are you not using $board[0] instead of $board0?

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli because i have multiple arrays and not just one array. $board[0] will tell me the first element in the array $board[]. I want to access all the elements of all the arrays so the thing will be something like $boards1[0] , $boards1[1] ... and so on. get it ?

Comment: You could have a multidimensional array, which is an array within an array, like $board[0][0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your examples, I believe this is your current code:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    $board = implode(',',${'boards'.$i});
    $query = "UPDATE schools SET board = '$board' where schoolcode = (some_no)";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error in updating table :".mysql_error());
}
```

If so, try altering it so it looks like this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    if(isset($_POST['boards'.$i]))
    {
        $board = mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',',$_POST['boards'.$i]));
        $query = "UPDATE schools SET board = '$board' where schoolcode = (some_no)";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error in updating table :".mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        echo '$_POST[\'boards' . $i . '\'] doesn\'t exist or is null.<br>';
    }
}
```

This contains an `if` condition, checking that the array entry actually exists. If it does exist, it runs the query. If it doesn't, it `echo`s back a message, telling you which one doesn't exist.

Even if you have confirmed at the frontend with Javascript, you should always check before running code, just to be sure it won't break it. You can never be too safe, especially if your code contains sensitive information.

Try this, and let me know how you go.

Comment: Please add escaping to $board before sending it to the query.

Comment: Good thinking @SebastiánGrignoli. I'll add that in now.

Comment: @Mohit, if you don't use mysql_real_escape_string($boards) you will be introducing a SQL injection vulnerability to your server.

Comment: Thank you both. I found out what was the error. I was passing the variables starting from `boards1[]` and so on whereas my for_loop used the counter starting from 0 so it was doing it as `boards0[]`. Damn it, I am such a noob. :( Thanks you all for your time.

Comment: No worries @Mohit. If in doubt, print what you're doing. Debug step number one. :)

Comment: Fine, but please, please, please, use mysql_real_escape_string($boards).  Your version will leave your database open to hackers.

Answer (score 1):

Assume `${'boards'.$i}` comes from `$_POST['boards'.$i]`. (If not, you are using `register_globals`, but that is not good.)

For multiple select, if no options is selected, then `$_POST['boards'.$i]` will give you `null` instead of an array.

Comment: In which case, the user simply needs to insert a `if` condition into the `for` loop surrounding the `implode` function. Something like `if(isset($_POST['boards'.$i]))` should do.

Comment: No i am using `$_POST['boards'.$i]` and not register globals. Also I assure you that none of the arrays is empty, i have done that validation at the front end using javascript.

Comment: This kind of validation should be done both client side and server side.